# How can i use ActiveX in chrome?

Tags: javascript, excel, google-chrome, activex

Is there any way to use Activex in chrome or other browsers?

I want to create the Excel file in JavaScript and save it to storage, I do that with ActiveX, But this code worked only in IE. Please tell me if there is other way for it.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use an ActiveX control for Chrome. Try to create a plug-in for non-IE browsers.
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not always be possible to use Internet Explorer to execute ActiveX content (e.g. on a Wine installation), nor may a user want to.

Check out this site as they did have some links to be able to run ActiveX on non-IE browsers:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX_control

Comment: I cant save my file from this ActiveX, its not support everything, just for medias.

Comment: you asked if you could use ActiveX from Chrome.  The link I sent provides your answer.  They also had a section of possible ways that you can get non-IE browsers to use ActiveX.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, in description of my question i told what am i want , but tank for your post jeff.